# Regex filter out out matches in list

Tags: regex

I need help to filter out names from a list.

**regex code i have so far which gets me everything**

```
(.*(SCARCP|SCDIRP).*)
```

**Example List of how i need to filter:**

```
SGP-SCARCP03 - MATCH
SIN-SCARCP03 - MATCH
SIN-SCARCP04 - FILTER OUT 
SIN-SCARCP06 - MATCH
SYD-SCARCP01 - MATCH
SYD-SCARCP02 - FILTER OUT 
TOK-SCARCP02 - MATCH
SIN-SCDIRP01 - MATCH
```

Comment: Why do yo match SIN-SCARCP03, but filter out SIN-SCARCP04? What is your criterion?

Comment: these are server names and i need two servers filtered out because they are test servers.

my actual list is much larger with 300 names.  I just need to filter out a couple

Comment: Unless you tell us what is the criterion, we cannot help you with you regex.

Comment: i cant just exclude one specific string ?

Comment: You surely can. But you have to tell the regex what the specifics is. Otherwise, how does it know whether to keep the string or not?

Comment: ok well its in the example.  I want to filter out 2 servers names from the list

Answer (score 0):

You should always tag a language as some implementations ("flavors") of regex support features that others do not. Also note that I added a few entries for the demos. I needed another -not result to demonstrate properly.

These two locations (`<<`) seem to imply that servers can have the same 'name' in different locations. That's unfortunate in this case (if you don't have list you can dynamically generate, which I'll get to in a bit).

```
SGP-SCARCP03 - MATCH
SIN-SCARCP03 - MATCH
SIN-SCARCP04 - FILTER OUT 
SIN-SCARCP06 - MATCH
SYD-SCARCP01 - MATCH
SYD-SCARCP02 - FILTER OUT  <<
TOK-SCARCP02 - MATCH       <<
SIN-SCDIRP01 - MATCH
```

If you need to enter these manually, this is your regex. Note that the `-1`s are a placeholder that I assume will never match. Just so you can see where you would need to enter a `|` delimited list as is done with `SYD-SCARCP(?!(?:02|99)\b)`

`^.*(SYD-SCARCP(?!(?:02|99)\b)|SGP-SCARCP(?!(?:-1)\b)|TOK-SCARCP(?!(?:-1)\b)|SIN-SCARCP(?!(?:04)\b)|SCDIRP(?!(?:02)\b)).*$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/i7N3Z5/2), note that the multiline flag is on, as well as the freespacing flag but that's only if you use the spaced-out regex)

```
^
.*?
(
  SYD-SCARCP
  (?!
    (?:02|99)
    \b
  )
|
  SGP-SCARCP
  (?!
    (?:-1)
    \b
  )
|
  TOK-SCARCP
  (?!
    (?:-1)
    \b
  )
|
  SIN-SCARCP
  (?!
    (?:04)
    \b
  )
|
  SCDIRP
  (?!
    (?:02)
    \b
  )
)
.*$
```

If you have two server names on the same line, this specific design likely will not work but it's faster than the alternative.

---

Now, as messy as that is, there may be some good news. If you do have a list, some database flag that marks development server or live server, such like that you can build an array of *production* server names (it's easier to match than to exclude.

Say for instance our built array is

`lives = {"SGP-SCARCP03","SIN-SCARCP03","SIN-SCARCP06","SYD-SCARCP01","TOK-SCARCP02","SIN-SCDIRP01"}`

I would possibly recommend sorting the string reverse alphabetically. Something like `lives.sort().reverse()`. The reversal can help alternation grab the appropriate string if two strings "overlap" say "**SGP-SCARCP03**" and "**SGP-SCARCP03**0" and "**SGP-SCARCP03**1"

You can use whatever `array.join/concat` method  your language may support

`livelist = strings.join(lives,"|")`

and build your regular expression as a string

`REFilter = "^.*?\b(?:" & liveslist & ")\b.*$"`

`\b` means word boundary in most flavors of RegEx.

In our case this would become

`.*?\b(?:SGP-SCARCP03|SIN-SCARCP03|SIN-SCARCP06|SYD-SCARCP01|TOK-SCARCP02|SIN-SCDIRP01)\b.*$`

I would also recommend sorting the array reverse-alphabetically before converting it the pipe-delimited list.

I recommended sorting the list reverse-alphabetically before. You could then, with some code wizardry, factor your regex string down so it looked more like

`(?:TOK-(?:SCARCP(?:02))|SYD-(?:SCARCP(?:01|07))|SIN-(?:SCARCP(?:06|03)|SCDIRP(?:01))|SGP-(?:SCARCP(?:03)))`

The reason to do this is less *backtracking* to find a match, though in many cases with simple expressions, the difference might not be noticeable.

and then

`^.*?(?:TOK-(?:SCARCP(?:02))|SYD-(?:SCARCP(?:01|07))|SIN-(?:SCARCP(?:06|03)|SCDIRP(?:01))|SGP-(?:SCARCP(?:03))).*$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/i7N3Z5/4)

And convert that final string to a an actual regex object in whatever language you're using.